# Can the block number be set back in ganache?

Tags: testing, ganache, blocks, timestamp, time

I know about tools like [ganache-time-traveler](https://github.com/ejwessel/GanacheTimeTraveler) that let you advance the block number.

But is it possible to go back to a lower value?

Answer (score 3):

The only option to do this is to use the [`takeSnapshot`](https://github.com/ejwessel/GanacheTimeTraveler#takesnapshot) and [`revertToSnapshot`](https://github.com/ejwessel/GanacheTimeTraveler#reverttosnapshotid_to_revert_to) functions in that same repo.

When you are at a state you know you want to return to, call `takeSnapshot` in order to get a snapshot ID. When you want to revert to that state, simply run `revertToSnapshot` with that specific ID.

As a note, the snapshotting function in Ganache was finicky the last time I used it (Feb 2019). There were certain limitations, such as not being able to take multiple snapshots before reverting to one. I do not know the current status of this.

---

#### Edit

The issues I was having with this feature are addressed in the "Custom Methods" section of the [ganache-cli repo](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#custom-methods):

> evm_snapshot : Snapshot the state of the blockchain at the current block. Takes no parameters. Returns the integer id of the snapshot created. A snapshot can only be used once. After a successful evm_revert, the same snapshot id cannot be used again. Consider creating a new snapshot after each evm_revert if you need to revert to the same point multiple times.
>
> evm_revert : Revert the state of the blockchain to a previous snapshot. Takes a single parameter, which is the snapshot id to revert to. This deletes the given snapshot, as well as any snapshots taken after (Ex: reverting to id 0x1 will delete snapshots with ids 0x1, 0x2, etc... If no snapshot id is passed it will revert to the latest snapshot. Returns true.

Comment: I used this, but it doesn't seem to lower the block number. It just resets the timestamp.

Comment: I wonder if that is a ganache-time-traveler specific thing? I do not see anything about it in the actual ganache-cli repo

Answer (score 1):

When using [`ganache-cli`](https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/ganache-cli/#command-line) you can specify the block as a parameter of the `fork` option by adding `@BLOCK_NUMBER` postfix, eg. to set to block 1599200:

```
ganache-cli --fork http://localhost:8545@1599200
```